# Absolute positioning for images within a div class

Tags: html, css

we have the following div structure, where we would like to horizontally center both the image and the text within the container div. However, the image is left aligned and only the title is centered.You could find the code below:

```css
.QHeader {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 96px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 415px;
  background-image: url('../img/bg_blue_rect.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
}
#QHeaderImg01 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 72px;
  width: 263px;
  height: 221px;
  background-color: #0F0;
}
.QHeaderTitle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 324px;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="QHeader">
  <img id="QHeaderImg01" src="img/q_header_img_01.png" />

  <div class="QHeaderTitle">
    TITLE
  </div>
  <!--QHeaderTitle-->

</div>
<!--QHeader-->
```

Comment: Do you need to absolutely position everything? Absolute positioning makes life difficult in general and should be avoided unless actually needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your `position: absolute;` or change it to `position: relative;`, as you will not need absolute positioning to horizontally center your elements:

```css
.QHeader {
  width: 800px;
  height: 415px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x415);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
}
#QHeaderImg01 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 263px;
  height: 221px;
  background-color: #0F0;
}
.QHeaderTitle {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="QHeader">
  <img id="QHeaderImg01" src="http://placehold.it/263x221/0c0" />

  <div class="QHeaderTitle">
    TITLE
  </div>
  <!--QHeaderTitle-->

</div>
<!--QHeader-->
```

Comment: Thanks to all respondents, the other two answers led me also to the result, but unfortunately i would just mark one answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
#QHeaderImg01 {
    position:absolute;
}
```

to

```
#QHeaderImg01 {
    position:relative;
}
```

and of cource, remove the big margin-top

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.container {
    height: 10em;
    position: relative }
div.container p {
    margin: 0;
   
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div class=container>
<IMG class="displayed" src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/1.jpg" alt="...">
  <p>Centered!
</div>
```

or

```css
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
 } 

div.container {
    height: 10em;
    position: relative }
div.container p {
    margin: 0;
   
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<IMG class="displayed" src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/1.jpg" alt="...">
<div class=container>
  <p>Centered!
</div>
```